# Cordova build iOS App' : "Could not find module 'npm-registry-client' (Node JS)

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova

I try to build my Cordova App' on Iphone without success. Everything is ok with Android and Windows Phone. I always have the same error when I try to build it on Iphone or iOS simulator : "Could Not find module 'npm-registry-client'".

Here's some screens:

PC:

[image: Visual studio error on Windows PC]

Mac (Remote Build):

[image: Remote Build on Mac]

I use Visual studio 2015 on Windows PC,Angular JS framework, Npm 2.11.3 and NodeJS 0.12.7 . I've already build a blank Iphone app' with Xcode 7 on my mac. I've tried to remove the node_modules folder and reinstall Npm but it's not working...

Any suggestions?

Thanks for reading

---

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

I found the solution. 'npm-registry-client' was installed on my Windows PC but not on my Mac. In terminal,just write "npm install npm-registry-client" and everything works great!! (Emulator and device)

Answer (score 0):

That error is most likely a bad install of Cordova on your Mac. Clearing out the installed Cordova version(s) from ~/.taco_home/node_modules will let the next build reinstall Cordova and should clear up the problem.

It's also possible but less likely that a Cordova install issue happened on your Windows machine instead. Reading the Output panel in VS will tell you if the error happened in the remote build log section or not.  If it didn't come from the remote build, then clearing your Cordova cache and your npm cache would be the needed fix.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time,I found my mistake but this could be solution for similar problem. ;)